# A tiny problems while throwing exception

Tags: java

I would like to ask about a problem i encountered while trying to make a method which can read text from a file.

For example, I created a simple interface, when you click the buttons, the text with a predefined folder path will be read.

So i use actionListener like this. Note that "einlesen" is "read" in German.

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
{
    Object source = e.getSource();
    if (source == einlesenDatei)
    {
        this.einlesen();
    }
    if (source == decoder)
    {
        this.decode();
    }
}
```

The problem is, the `readInput` method required me to throw a `FileNotFoundException`, and the `actionPerformed` method requires me to cut off the throw exception part.

Comment: can you post whatever code you have?

Comment: i tried to post a picture , when you click "methode" with hyperlink you should see it :(

Comment: you have to handle exception in actionPerformed and display appropriate message for user if exception is thrown

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can put the code for `read` method in a `try catch` block like this:

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    Object source = e.getSource();
    if (source == inputFile) {
        try {
            this.readInput();
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            // handle the exception
        }
    }
    if (source == decoder) {
        this.decode();
    }
}
```

Comment: you mean inside the methode "actionPerformed" ? 

i will try anyway, thanks for your help !